# .htaccess rewrite engine + redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to rewrite URLs like in the example below:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php  <=>  http://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=de  <=> http://www.domain.com/de
http://www.domain.com/index.php?p1=something  <=>  http://www.domain.com/something
http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=de&param1=something  <=>  http://www.domain.com/de/something
http://www.domain.com/index.php?p1=something&p2=something-else  <=>  http://www.domain.com/something/something-else
http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=de&p1=something&p2=something-else  <=>  http://www.domain.com/de/something/something-else
```

The rules should allow other locales to be added, not just DE.
Also when user comes to e.g. http://domain.com/de/, he should be redirected with 301 to http://domain.com/de (so the trailing slashes will not create duplicate URLs)

Can you please provide me with some help? Thanks a lot.

EDIT

I tried to filter out needed folders and then I was stuck at first parameter

```
#Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

#rewrite all physical existing file or folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#allow things that are certainly necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/media/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/script/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/style/"

#rewrite rules
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?lang=$1 [QSA]

#add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/de` and `http://www.domain.com/something` aren't they both following same pattern?

Comment: Probably yes, I just wanted to make a distiction between a locale and other parameters.

Comment: if they're both the same, then there's no distinction between locale and the other parameters

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: Updated with my starting code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)[^/]$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&p1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(\w{3,})/?$ /index.php?p1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)